# Menu icon is not showing on toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

Please help me find out why some icons are not displayed on the menu?

I want to add menu handler to my project.

I read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html too, it's very simple but the icon is not shown. I tried a lot to find a solution but I did not get a success.

Can some one help me please?

### activity_main.xml:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Activity:-

```
/**
     * onCreateOptionsMenu
     * @param menu
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchitem);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        TextView searchText = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

        searchText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        searchText.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        searchText.setHint("Type text here...");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * onOptionsItemSelected
     * @param item
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

### menu:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: did you add this **`toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ar_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`**

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the `Menu` items to display in the toolbar you must add `setSupportActionBar`

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```